# passing context to non-activity class for a dbHelper in Android

Tags: android, sqlite, android-context

I am trying to load a SQLite Database from a non-activity class

I need the context for the `DBHelper` Adapter class and using a `ApplicationContextProvider` class as outlined below. (I have not added this to the manifest as some tutorials suggest however as I am not sure how.)

```
CNYearsAdapter myCNYearsAdapter = new CNYearsAdapter( ApplicationContextProvider.getContext());
```

Application context provider:

```
package com.example.kuachart;

import android.app.Application;
import android.content.Context;


public class ApplicationContextProvider extends Application {

/**
 * Keeps a reference of the application context
 */
private static Context sContext;

@Override
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();

    sContext = getApplicationContext();

}

/**
 * Returns the application context
 *
 * @return application context
 */
public static Context getContext() {
    return sContext;
}

}
```

Currently the line above that instantiates `myCNYearsAdapter` crashes the program so I am not sure if the Application context provider is working correctly. Is there another way to get the context passed to this non-activity class?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You ***do*** have to add it to the manifest, otherwise `ApplicationContextProvider` won't be instantiated, `onCreate()` will never be called and `sContent` will remain `null`.

In your manifest's `application` tag do the following:

```
<application 
     android:name="your.package.name.ApplicationContextProvider"
 ...
```

> is there another way to get the context passed to this non-activity class?

Well, you could always pass the Context from the Activity to the non-activity class.

```
public class NonActivity {

    private Context mContext;

    public NonActivity(Context context){
        mContext = context;
    }

    public void someMethod(){
        CNYearsAdapter myCNYearsAdapter = new CNYearsAdapter(mContext);
        // do something
    }

}
```

Inside an Activity:

```
NonActivity na = new NonActivity(this);
na.someMethod();
```

Answer (score 0):

Add `ApplicationContextProvider aa = new ApplicationContextProvider(this);` in your activity from where you have created, you will be asked to create a simple method in `ApplicationContextProvider`, from there you can use your `Activity's` context.

Answer (score 0):

I noticed in my constructor that there was a context passed in but there was no accessor when I needed it later. I added a private Context myContext; and then set its value in the constructor. Then I could use it later

```
public class TaskExpandListAdapter extends SimpleCursorTreeAdapter {
    private myDBHelper helper;
    private Context myContext; // define an object instance variable

    public TaskExpandListAdapter(Context context, Cursor cursor, int groupLayout,
                                 String[] groupFrom, int[] groupTo, int childLayout,
                                 String[] childFrom, int[] childTo) {
        super(context, cursor, groupLayout, groupFrom, groupTo, childLayout, childFrom, childTo);
        myContext = context; // set its value in the constructor
    }

    public Cursor fetchChildren(int groupID) {
        helper = new myDBHelper(myContext); //use it to access sqlite
        SQLiteDatabase sqlDB = helper.getReadableDatabase();
```

Note that I'm trying to create an expandable list view from sqlite tables